# How to update data using room database?

Tags: android, database, android-room

I am using Room database and I want to update a row. I am able to update the row but getting this warning

> 12-05 20:59:17.635 29363-29372/com.example.parmarravi21.recyclerviewiv W/SQLiteConnectionPool: A SQLiteConnection object for database '/data/user/0/com.example.parmarravi21.recyclerviewiv/databases/RecP10' was leaked!  Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly and to close the database when it is no longer needed.

This is my code

```
//defining database
        db = Room.databaseBuilder(getActivity(), AppDatabase.class, "RecP10")
                .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                .allowMainThreadQueries().build();

      TimeDateModel timeDateModel = new TimeDateModel(positionTime, TimeMode);

                        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
                        contentValues.put("posItem", timeDateModel.getPosItem());
                        contentValues.put("TimeDateMode", timeDateModel.getTimeDateMode());

                        if (db.timeDao().getItemAtTimePos(positionTime) != null) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "updated database");
                            db.beginTransaction();
                            try {
                                db.getOpenHelper().getWritableDatabase().update("Datetime", 0,
                                                contentValues, "posItem =" + positionTime, null);
                                db.setTransactionSuccessful();
                            } finally {
                                db.endTransaction(); // commit or rollback
                                db.close();

                            }
                        } else {
                            Log.e(TAG, "New item added");
                            db.timeDao().insertAll(timeDateModel);
                        }
```

I have also tried the dao update function but the data is not updating .

```
db.timeDao().update(timeDateModel);
```

I am new to database in android please help me out .

[Github link for complete code](https://github.com/parmarravi/HorizontalRecyclerView)

Comment: "Is there any way to update data?" -- yes, use an `@Update` method on the `@Dao`. "The data remains same in database and not getting updated" -- how are you determining this?

Comment: Hi @CommonsWare , i am using  this [link]( http://sqliteviewer.flowsoft7.com/)  to verify the data in database it is still showing old data even after using db.blinkSingleDao().update(blinkSingleModel); am i doing something wrong here?

Comment: Well, I do not know if you are downloading the changed database from your device or emulator, or how you are getting that changed database to that tool. [Here is a sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-androidarch/tree/v0.6/Trips/RoomBasics) from [my book](https://commonsware.com/AndroidArch/) that shows the use of `@Update`, complete with instrumentation tests that show that it works.

Comment: I used  this code to update data `db.getOpenHelper().getWritableDatabase().update(dataSet.get(nextPos).getName(), 0, contentValues, "posItem =" + nextPos, null);`

Comment: Hey, if you still stuck then try setting your primary key by first getting it from db. Room needs your correct primary key value to update your entries.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Query("UPDATE Test SET test_name=:arg1,test_startDate=:arg2,test_endDate=:arg3,test_location=:arg4,test_ringerMode=:arg5,test_latitude=:arg6,test_longitude=:arg7 WHERE testId = :arg0")
fun updateTest( testId: Int,testName:String,testStartTime:String,testEndTime:String,testLocation:String,testRingerMode:Int,testLatitude:Double,testLongitude:Double)
```

Try coding this way.

Answer (score 0):

Using an @Update annotation should do the trick , and according to the Android developer Documentation, you shouldn't perform database Queries on the main Thread ,thus might cause your database issues

Something like these

```
@Update
void updateTimeEntry(TimeEntry timeEntry)
```

with TimeEntry being the name of your model class